# Heroku debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am building an application with Heroku and having some problems.
I want to debug some content like I do with rails server:

> logger.debug '...'

How can I do that in Heroku, so I can see the debugging in heroku logs? (or anything else..)

Thanks!

Comment: same here, great question mate...

Comment: Same problem on cedar stack.  It seems that the logger.debug in models are output fine. but logger.debug in controllers are not in output. Anyone with more updated info?

Answer (score 12):

The Cedar stack in Heroku does not appear to be responsive to the LOG_LEVEL config (env) variable that works for previous stacks (I use the logging:expanded addon).  I tried setting LOG_LEVEL to both `debug` and `DEBUG` without success.

Only by setting `config.log_level = :debug` in config/environments/production.rb am I able to see the output of 'logger.debug'.

Answer (score 12):

Been fighting with this for a long time, solution is nice and simple:

Set in production.rb instead of

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

place:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

and you get the full logging output.

Comment: at where we will get full logging output , do you means in heroku logs -t ?

Comment: no i was not :( & im using raiols 6 , may be it is included by default in it

Comment: Ah sorry, my answer is outdated then since 2012. Yes, maybe you are right.

Answer (score 9):

`heroku logs` on your command line will give you the logs for the current app. If you have [expanded logging](http://addons.heroku.com/logging) turned on you can tail this output

Comment: FYI: tailing shows you the real time output and is done by heroku logs --tail

Answer (score 6):

Using Rails 3.2, we made this configurable by modifying **config/environments/{environment}.rb** to drive it from an environment variable:

```
config.log_level = ENV["LOG_LEVEL"].to_sym if ENV["LOG_LEVEL"]
```

Then, we can modify the Heroku config variable to change it:

```
heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug --app <app name>
```

This lets us easily log more or less as needed.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Comment: This works. Setting config.log_level or config.logger.level to debug had no effect. Inspecting in console revealed that Rails.logger.level was always the default info. However, setting the config variable did the trick.

Comment: @TimoLehto for the lazy it's `Rails.logger.level = 0` for :debug level

Answer (score 1):

To write to your logs on Heroku, instead of using `logger.debug "..."` simply use `puts`:

```
puts "..."
```

You *don't* even need to set the `config.log_level` setting in `config/environments/production.rb`.

[See the docs here.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log)

Comment: YES YES YES this worked a treat. Just do 'puts' no stuffing around required. Thankyou!

Comment: yes. And then just delete the puts when you want to go into production. I have NO IDEA why every language ever used for web development has some sort of logger class with levels you can set. It seems so completely useless!

Comment: Michael, I fear your sarcasm might be lost on Evolve and user664833 - obviously the reason that logger classes exist is so that you don't need to delete (or re-add) puts statements when moving from dev to production, or when trying to debug an error, etc. - just change the log_level.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.log_level = ENV['APP_LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['APP_LOG_LEVEL'].to_sym : :error
```

Comment: You better explain your explanation than just posting some anonymous code section. You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)