# Heroku troubleshooting details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to debug a Heroku app.  I'm having trouble with local Rails, so I'm using Heroku to debug.  I'm getting an HTTP 500 response from some of my POST requests, and the only thing Heroku is willing to tell me is:

```
$ heroku logs
... lots of other stuff ...
POST app.heroku.com/games dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=36ms status=500 bytes=0
```

How can I get more information than this about my server error?

Comment: Check the output of $ heroku logs

Comment: @cmpolis: That's where I got my output.  Sorry I didn't make that clearer.

Comment: You'd want to turn up the LOG_LEVEL too. Check this question for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994492/heroku-debugging. I'd also recommend using the free level of Loggly for easier log inspection.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [Heroku logging](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)? In your local application directory:

```
$ heroku logs
```

You could also try expanded logging

```
$ heroku addons:upgrade logging:expanded
$ heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: That's where I got my output.  Sorry I didn't make that clearer.

Comment: OK. Take a look at the support page I linked for expanded logging options. Will edit answer.

Comment: Looks quite useful, but unfortunately for me, Heroku requires verification before installing any addon, and I don't have credit card information to give it.  Is there an alternative that doesn't require a Heroku addon?  I doubt it, but I have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch server errors in Rails and log them. The simplest way to do that is to add a `rescue_from` clause in your controller. That will let you define a method to be invoked when an uncaught exception bubbles up from your code.

```
rescue_from UserNotFoundError, :with => :user_not_found

def throw
  #Triggers a UserNotFound error
  @user = User.find(42)
end

def user_not_found(exception)
  Rails.logger.warn { "User not found\n#{exception.backtrace.join("\n\t")}" }

  @message = "Exception logged."
  render :errors
end
```

For bonus points, you can add that to your base `ApplicationController` class.

I am working on [Progstr Logger](http://addons.heroku.com/progstr), a free Heroku add-on that makes storing and searching through logs easier. We also have an [online example](http://rails.progstr.com/controller/errors) that does a similar thing to catch errors.