# heroku crashes with no data about error, just http 500

Tags: php, heroku

i got my app at heroku server through git, now stuff that works on my local php server keeps crashing, BUT - whereas for a crash on localhost a php engine would always give me information about the error, here i just get HTTP500.

For example - if i create empty php where all i do is divide by zero, easyphp gives me warnings\notices, while heroku server does nothing at all - empty page.

Right now the server crashes because of a DB related string( i checked), but all the feedback it gives is HTTP500 error, no details. On localhost this string works. How am i supposed to find out what's the problem? is there a way to get any feedback from heroku server?

Comment: similarly look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994492/heroku-debugging you probably need to change your security/debugging settings but for your PHP app instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `heroku logs`!  Apache should log the actual exception.

Comment: I still only get the error code using the tyler buildpack:

Comment: 2014-07-15T12:52:04.789356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/test" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=ID fwd="XX.XX.XX.X" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=220ms status=500 bytes=2825

Comment: @Ben If that's the only data in your logging then your PHP code is not properly producing error output to STDERR or STDOUT... which is stereotypically broken of a default PHP setup.  Adjust your settings to get proper logging of errors (or use a different buildpack) and try again to work on tracking down the error.

Comment: The buildpack I use uses NGINX: github.com/ustramooner/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler I've set the log level to debug: 
  error_log           logs/error.log debug;

Comment: As Heroku now has an official PHP buildpack, I recommend giving that a spin.