# Why can't I see any logging output from Rails on my heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, heroku

If I try things like

```
puts "12345"
```

or

```
logger.debug "abcde"
```

in my controller, and then access, that controller... I then run

```
heroku logs
```

or

```
heroku logs -n 1000
```

and I do not see any of the logging output. How can I output logs to my heroku server and view them?

Answer (score 3):

From [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging):

... when using the Ruby on Rails TaggedLogger by ActiveSupport, you should add the following into your app’s configuration to get stdout logging:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. I have that line in my production, development, and test files. I also am trying output via `logger.debug "message"` and` puts "message"` immediately at the beginning of my controller. However, `heroku logs` shows nothing but a simple POST to the controller with no log statements.

Comment: Have you checked this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994492/heroku-debugging)?

Answer (score 1):

we found that the easiest thing to do here is to install the add-on "Papertrail" from the heroku add-ons page. When you then click on Papertrail on your Resources tab, you get a good log view